# user on nfs share

Tags: permissions, nfs, ownership

How can I specify which user a new file created on the NFS share is owned by?
I.e. I've mounted a share on a client, `userA` is creating a file but that file shows as being owned by `userB` (possibly due to owner id staying consistent). How can I specify on server that all new files end up owned by `userC` e.g.?

Comment: Who have you mounted the share as?

Comment: @RamanSailopal an NFS share must be mounted by root.

Answer (score 1):

NFS expects uids and gids to be consistent across all servers.

File ownerships are mapped by uid rather than by name, so if you have userA as 1000 on the client, when it creates a file on the server that file will be owned by uid 1000. The server or a different client may see uid 1000 as a different user name.

If you're using NFS you should homogenise your uid/gid relationships